# Target an array index when updating JSON data?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I have a column of JSON data that I need to update; the problem is that I need to dynamically target the index of an array within the JSON (specifically, by DocumentTemplatePageId). Here's the structure of my JSON, showing the page object that I need to modify; *what I want to do is add to, edit, or delete from the IssuesList node on any given Page object.*

```
{ "Pages":
    [
        {
            "DocumentTemplatePageId": "C359FB3F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F",
            "DocumentTemplatePageTypeId": 9,
            "PageData": {
              "IssuesList": [
                {
                  "IssueOrderNumber": 1,
                  "Description": "Houston, we have a problem.",
                  "Resolution": "We are working on it.",
                  "Severity": 5,
                  "DueDate": "2024-01-15"
                },
                {
                  "IssueOrderNumber": 2,
                  "Description": "We have issues with employee retention.",
                  "Resolution": "We will start giving retention bonuses.",
                  "Severity": 2,
                  "DueDate": "2023-12-30"
                },
                {
                  "IssueOrderNumber": 3,
                  "Description": "Increasing incidents of sexual harassment.",
                  "Resolution": "Sexual harassment training is now doubled, and an independent investigator/arbitrator has been hired.",
                  "Severity": 3,
                  "DueDate": "2023-12-01"
                }
              ]
            }
        },
        { repeat N times }
    ]
}
```

I can target a specific DocumentTemplatePageId and update its data using JSON_MODIFY, as follows:

```
DECLARE @cdtid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  = '2380493F-F36B-1410-8C7D-006D55A93A8F'
DECLARE @pageid uniqueidentifier = 'C359FB3F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F' --'1A5AFB3F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F' --'F472F93F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F'
DECLARE @strNewJsonIssuesValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"IssueOrderNumber":1,"Description":"Houston, we have a problem.","Resolution":"We are working on it.","Severity":5,"DueDate":"/Date(1705298400000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":2,"Description":"We have issues with employee retention.","Resolution":"We will start giving retention bonuses.","Severity":2,"DueDate":"/Date(1703916000000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":3,"Description":"Increasing incidents of harassment.","Resolution":"Harassment training is now doubled, and an independent investigator/arbitrator has been hired.","Severity":3,"DueDate":"/Date(1701410400000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":4,"Description":"My descr","Resolution":"My reso","Severity":5,"DueDate":"/Date(1709294400000)/"}]'

DECLARE @originalJsonIssues NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
SELECT
  j1.IssuesList
FROM dbo.CompanyxDocumentTemplate cdt
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(cdt.JsonData, '$.Pages')
  WITH (
    DocumentTemplatePageId uniqueidentifier,
    DocumentTemplatePageTypeId int,
    IssuesList nvarchar(max) '$.PageData.IssuesList' AS JSON
  ) j1
WHERE cdt.Id = @cdtid
AND j1.DocumentTemplatePageId = @pageid
FOR JSON PATH
)

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(40) = '$[0].IssuesList'

-- Insert the new data
SET @originalJsonIssues = JSON_MODIFY(@originalJsonIssues, @path, @strNewJsonIssuesValue)
```

Having updated the IssuesList node for a specific page, I'm stumped on how I might insert that chunk of data into the overall JSON. I imagine it would take a series of complex JSON_QUERY statements to do the job... (I even considered taking the coward's way out by just doing a big string replace).

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. Do you have another table of `DocumentTemplatePageId` that you need to match along with new JSON? How about you show us what your table(s) look like now and how you want them to look. (Rather than showing us just a single query that you already did)

Comment: Everything is taking place in a single table (dbo.CompanyxDocumentTemplate). What I need to do is modify the JSON data in a column from that table. I realize that the JSON data would normally be broken out and stored in a relational table, but the solution has been architected in this way to make it more extensible. Hope this helps your understanding!

Comment: Can you show us sample data and expected results ([as a table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/14868997)) because it's not easy to understand

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface; I've edited the OP to try to better explain the situation.

Comment: No I want a full table in markup format for example `|Id|JsonData|` newline `|--|--|` newline `|1|{SomeJsonHere}|` along with expected results for that. And it's still not clear exactly what you want or why what you have doesn't work. You say "how I might insert that chunk of data into the overall JSON." but you have that already using `JSON_MODIFY`. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the whole JSON inside an `APPLY`, then just `UPDATE` based on that

```sql
DECLARE @cdtid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  = '2380493F-F36B-1410-8C7D-006D55A93A8F';
DECLARE @pageid uniqueidentifier = 'C359FB3F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F'; --'1A5AFB3F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F' --'F472F93F-F36B-1410-8C7C-006D55A93A8F'
DECLARE @strNewJsonIssuesValue NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"IssueOrderNumber":1,"Description":"Houston, we have a problem.","Resolution":"We are working on it.","Severity":5,"DueDate":"/Date(1705298400000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":2,"Description":"We have issues with employee retention.","Resolution":"We will start giving retention bonuses.","Severity":2,"DueDate":"/Date(1703916000000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":3,"Description":"Increasing incidents of harassment.","Resolution":"Harassment training is now doubled, and an independent investigator/arbitrator has been hired.","Severity":3,"DueDate":"/Date(1701410400000)/"},{"IssueOrderNumber":4,"Description":"My descr","Resolution":"My reso","Severity":5,"DueDate":"/Date(1709294400000)/"}]';


UPDATE cdt
SET cdt.JsonData = j.NewJson
FROM dbo.CompanyxDocumentTemplate cdt
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      j1.DocumentTemplatePageId,
      j1.DocumentTemplatePageTypeId,
      IIF(j1.DocumentTemplatePageId = @pageid, @strNewJsonIssuesValue, j1.IssueList) AS [PageData.IssuesList]
    FROM OPENJSON(cdt.JsonData, '$.Pages')
      WITH (
        DocumentTemplatePageId uniqueidentifier,
        DocumentTemplatePageTypeId int,
        IssuesList nvarchar(max) '$.PageData.IssuesList' AS JSON
      ) j1
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Pages')
) j(NewJson)
WHERE cdt.Id = @cdtid;
```

You could also add further joins. For example:

```sql
UPDATE cdt
SET cdt.JsonData = j.NewJson
FROM dbo.CompanyxDocumentTemplate cdt
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      j1.DocumentTemplatePageId,
      j1.DocumentTemplatePageTypeId,
      ISNULL(jd.NewIssueList, j1.IssueList) AS [PageData.IssuesList]
    FROM OPENJSON(cdt.JsonData, '$.Pages')
      WITH (
        DocumentTemplatePageId uniqueidentifier,
        DocumentTemplatePageTypeId int,
        IssuesList nvarchar(max) '$.PageData.IssuesList' AS JSON
      ) j1
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NewJsonData jd ON jd.DocumentTemplatePageId = j1.DocumentTemplatePageId
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Pages')
) j(NewJson)
WHERE cdt.Id = @cdtid;
```